# Best practice for deploying ssis package to SQL server behind firewall

Tags: sql-server, ssis, firewall

We recently had one of our SQL Servers relocated to be behind internal corporate firewall. We are all behind corporate firewall, but now some SQL Servers are being segregated behind internal firewalls hence we cannot direct connect to them from our local computer; access is only from the IIS web servers. Development/maintenance is going to be a PITA.

Previously one of our engineers who was maintaining our SSIS package would connect directly to the database and deploy with their Visual Studio or SSMS. Now they cannot direct connect. We have limited permissions on the servers which can connect to the SQL Server; we cannot install VS on those servers, not can they use SSMS because it results in folder create permission issue.

I feel this probably a typical corporate design in these days of higher security. So what is  the proper approach(es) for an engineer to get their SSIS package deployed/updated to SQL Servers they don't have direction connection (SQL connection) abilities?

Comment: Sounds like someone has gone a little too far with permissions and security and actually broke the workflows; the DBAs need to be able to connect to the servers, they can't do their job if they can't...

Comment: Beyond Thom's excellent observation, the approach would be to use automated deploy utilities

Comment: @billinkc ... ah, setting a cicd process for these deploys.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question, as a comment from billinkc, a proper approach would be to set up some cicd process (Jenkins, perhaps) to do the automated deploy.